# Razor 'IF' and Kendo Template 'IF'

Tags: kendo-ui

How would you go about in using a Razor 'if' to check on condition, then using a Kendo template 'if' to check another condition. For example,

```
@if (User.IsInRole(Roles.Homeroom.Administrator))
    {
        #if (Approved) {#
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="approveCoach(#=Id#)">Approve</button>
        </div>
        #}#
    }
```

The code is giving me red squiggles.

Comment: Do the "red squiggles" actually prevent this from working in any way?  Does the code compile?  Does the client-side code look like it should?  The "red squiggles" may just mean that the view's intellisense doesn't quite understand the syntax of your code, which isn't uncommon when working with more complex client-side libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way around this is to just switch the 'if' conditions, which is okay in my case. I believe by trying to do it the other way, the Razor 'if' tries to read the '#if' as a C# reference instead of a Kendo Template conditional statement. I'm sure there's some other way around this, but it seems easier to just switch the ifs around in my case.

```
#if (!Approved) {#
    @if (User.IsInRole(Roles.Homeroom.Administrator))
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="approveCoach(#=Id#)">Approve</button>
        </div>
    }
    #}#
```